# Error while creating an SQLite table consisting of a PK and 4 Foreign Keys

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

This is my statement for creating an SQLite table to store a primary key and 4 foreign keys.

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_CHEMISTID_DATE_ORDERNUMBER_ORDERDATA = "CREATE TABLE "
        + CHEMISTID_DATE_ORDERNUMBER_ORDERDATA + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
        + KEY_CHEMISTID_ID + " INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY(" + KEY_CHEMISTID_ID + ") REFERENCES " + CHEMISTID + "(" + KEY_ID + "), "
        + KEY_DATE_ID + " INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY(" + KEY_DATE_ID + ") REFERENCES " + DATE + "(" + KEY_ID + "), " 
        + KEY_ORDERNUMBER_ID + " INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY(" + KEY_ORDERNUMBER_ID + ") REFERENCES " + ORDERNUMBER + "(" + KEY_ID + "), "
        + KEY_ORDERDATA_ID + " INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY(" + (KEY_ORDERDATA_ID) + ") REFERENCES " + ORDERDATA + "(" + KEY_ID + "))";
```

When I run my application I get an error:

```
 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "date_id": syntax error (code 1): ,    while compiling: CREATE TABLE chemistId_date_orderNumber_orderData(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, chemistId_id INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY(chemistId_id) REFERENCES chemistIdTable(id), date_id INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY(date_id) REFERENCES dateTable(id), orderNumber_id INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY(orderNumber_id) REFERENCES orderNumberTable(id), orderData_id INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY(orderData_id) REFERENCES orderDataTable(id))
```

What is the error in the statement and how should I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your `FK`s at the end of your query like this:

```
private static final String DATABASE_ACTIVITIES_CREATE = "create table activity "
        + "( _id integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + "name text not null, "
        + "date long, "
        + "operator text, "
        + "category_id long, "
        + "descripiton text,"
        + "project_id long,"
        + "FOREIGN KEY(project_id) REFERENCES project(_id),"
        + "FOREIGN KEY(category_id) REFERENCES category(_id));";
```